# How to get access to protected field of a Button?

Tags: java, android, reflection

We have method in Android for setting OnClickListener for a Button (button.setOnClickListener(....), but no .getOnClickListener.

I need to get listener assigned to a Button and save it in variable.

OnClickListener is protected field of Button class, inherited from TextView, inherited from View class. Name of the field "mOnClickListener". I can't get it even through reflection:

```
    ...
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    OnClickListener listener = getListener(button1);
    ...

    public OnClickListener getListener(Button b) {

 java.lang.reflect.Field field =  b.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener");
...
    }
```

getting "noSuchFieldException". Any ideas to make it possible?

PS I know other ways to make my app work without reflection, just wondering why it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the method `getClass` in your class. Instead you should call `getClass` on an object of the `Button` class, or use the class field:

```
Button.class.getSuperClass().getSuperClass().getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener"):
```

Another way to do that:

```
Button.class.getField("mOnClickListener");
```

The method getField includes fields that are inherited from super classes.

Comment: getClass() is non-static method, so it can't be called on Button. I've used Button.class.getDeclaredField(...), but result is the same. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Results are the same with b.getClass() and Button.class - checked just now. And getField() does not return non-public fields.

Answer (score 1):

You wanna make the field accessible.

So you'll basically wind up with something like

```
Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener");
f.setAccessible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because your are not *starting* from the button. Instead do this :

```
 java.lang.reflect.Field field =  View.class.getField("mOnClickListener");
```

and when you have the field make it accessible:

```
try{
   field.setAccessible(true);
   Object clickListener = field.get(b);
   field.setAccessible(false);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank You. But the issue is something differs, because I had setAcessile(true) and got 239 other fields but not what I was searching for :) Maybe there are no such field? I found it here, Line 1542: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/view/View.java?av=h#View

Comment: you can use your debugger to see if the field is there or not